# Silverlight 4.0: MultiDataTrigger

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, triggers, silverlight-4.0, datatrigger

Is there a way just like multidatatrigger behavior of WPF also implemented in Silverlight 4.0?

OR

Another workaround which behaves like multidatatrigger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, neither MultiBindings nor MultiValueConverters exist in Silverlight by default, although some very clever people have ported them over:

http://www.thejoyofcode.com/MultiBinding_for_Silverlight_3.aspx

As for MultiDataTriggers, there is no direct equivalent, although you could probably hack together a close equivalent using the above (i.e., set a multibinding, set the inputs to the multibinding as your trigger conditions, and use a MultiValueConverter to coalesce the result)